# Create Web Service for get soap messages

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

Actually, I had to make the request.
But service providers will not test sending any messages until after going through certain steps
So I need to create a website to test the messages I send.
How can I create a web service to receive soap messages below?

```
Content-ID: <ebxhmheader111@example.com>
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/envelope.xsd
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd">
<SOAP:Header>
<eb:MessageHeader SOAP:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
<eb:From>
<eb:PartyId>urn:duns:123456789</eb:PartyId>
</eb:From>
<eb:To>
<eb:PartyId>urn:duns:912345678</eb:PartyId>
</eb:To>
<eb:CPAId>20001209-133003-28572</eb:CPAId>
<eb:ConversationId>20001209-133003-28572</eb:ConversationId>
<eb:Service>urn:services:SupplierOrderProcessing</eb:Service>
<eb:Action>NewOrder</eb:Action>
<eb:MessageData>
<eb:MessageId>20001209-133003-28572@example.com</eb:MessageId>
<eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:12:12</eb:Timestamp>
</eb:MessageData>
</eb:MessageHeader>
</SOAP:Header>
<SOAP:Body>
<eb:Manifest eb:version="2.0">
<eb:Reference xlink:href="cid:ebxmlpayload111@example.com" xlink:role="XLinkRole" xlink:type="simple">
<eb:Description xml:lang="en-US">Purchase Order 1</eb:Description>
</eb:Reference>
</eb:Manifest>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
--BoundarY
Content-ID: <ebxmlpayload111@example.com>
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<purchase_order>
<po_number>1</po_number>
<part_number>123</part_number>
<price currency="USD">500.00</price>
</purchase_order>
--BoundarY––
```

Comment: You do not need a website.  There are URL schema in the xml and you just need to verify the files meet the schema.  So just running a schema check should work.

Comment: l check my xml file with schema it'correct but it didn't prove that the request was submitted correctly.
I worried about sending multipart/relaed,Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: How do you know that you are testing correctly?  The schema test will be the same or better than your own test. Once you get one request submitted correctly all will be the same.  what do you plan to test that isn't already tested by the schema?  Suppose you did a test for SSL/TLS and you used a different encryption algorithm or key from vendor.  Your test will pass but it still won't work with vendor site.  Unless the vendor created the test, your test would do nothing.

Comment: Ok I can only test shcema for other parts.I have to wati for vender.Thank you so much for comment